# Extra 0 in starting of the output of decimal to binary code conversion

Tags: binary, decimal, output

I seem to have a problem in the output of my code (A decimal to binary conversion code). If I enter a number, for example 12, it'll output 01100. I just want it to output 1100 (without the 0 in the very first). Is there something that I may have missed?
Thank you in advance! Here is my code below :

```
import java.util.*;
public class DtoB{    
public static void main(String[] args){    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");    
    int number = in.nextInt();    

    int i; 
    int j; 
    int[] binary = new int[10]; 

    if ( number > 0 ){
    for (i = 0; number != 0;  i++){
        binary[i] = number % 2; 
        number /= 2; 
    } 
    for ( j = i; j >= 0; j-- ){ 
        System.out.print(binary[j]);
        } 
        System.out.print(" is the binary conversion of your integer."); 

    } else {
        System.out.print("Error: You have not entered a positive integer.");
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: intialize j with i-1 and try

Comment: What is the "array." Did u miss anything while pasting code?

Comment: Thank you. Now I'll just trace the code manually to see how it did that. Thank you again :)

Comment: Ah, "array" is a part of a comment that I have missed to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize j with i-1

```
for ( j = i-1; j >= 0; j-- ){ 
    System.out.print(binary[j]);
}
```